# Travelling to US by rental car from Canada - NOT Canadian Citizen

Tags: international-travel, car-rentals

I'm looking to do a quick round trip to US from Canada by land, driving a rental car.

Are there any additional documents needed to cross the border given that I'm not a citizen of Canada?

Any additional arrangements with the rental company (Hertz)?

For US air travel, this is what I bring:

- Passport with Canada TRV and US Tourist Visa
- Canadian Post Graduate Work Permit

Comment: I've done this and it was no problem.  At the border, all they asked was my passport.

Comment: in many cases it may be worth traveling to the US and renting the car there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the time you rent the car, make sure that:

- The rental agreement expressly allows the car to be driven into and within the US.
- The car will be covered by insurance while you're driving in the US. This good-in-the-US insurance may cost more than what you'd pay if the rental car were only driven in Canada.
- The rental company has provided you with a card or letter evidencing the good-in-the-US insurance coverage.

Comment: It's worthwhile to note that the renter may already have sufficient insurance; if the renter owns a car and therefore has auto insurance it would be a good idea to check the terms of that policy before buying insurance from the rental company.  I was thinking of posting an answer saying essentially this, but it occurred to me that I don't know about obtaining an I-94 form in advance.  I believe that it's possible and that it would allow the traveler not to have to leave the vehicle (unless selected for secondary inspection for another reason). This would fall under "additional documents."

Comment: That's certainly reasonable. The OP gives no indication, however, if they already own a vehicle in Canada.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, completely forgot I posted this. I do not have my own vehicle and will try to confirm with Hertz per your suggestion.